# Implementing a multi-parameter search service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

I would like to design a search service which applies to a multiple set of different request paramaters. It could be called with one parameter only, or with more.

The problem is that some of the params could only be used solely, or are mutually exclusive with others.

Another problem is that some params are really required, while others are only optional.

The easiest way to resolve this is to involve a series of if-statements in the controller's search method, checking for the existence of some parameters or sets of parameters, and reacting correspondingly. Coming from the world of Java however, I have been taught to disbelieve anything that ends up in a bunch of if or switch statements. Back there, we often resort to factories, to which we delegate the decision to choose a proper search strategy from a bunch of strategy classes. All that was ever necessary, was to configure a proper mapping between request parameters and strategy classes.

I also know that the Rails dev mentality tends to solve about problem in a much less abstract and more business-like manner.

What is the proper way to make complex multi-parameter search service?

Answer (score 0):

Rails 2: searchlogic

Rails 3: meta_search

Then it's as easy as Model.search(params[:search])

Sleep easy.